# Word or phrase for potentially ineffective "shotgun approach," before the discovery of gunpowder?

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms, synonyms

I'm looking to describe a potentially ineffective process that is similar to the shotgun approach, but before the discovery of gunpowder.

The setting is a fantasy setting, if that provides valuable context.

> They threw everything at him. The *shotgun approach* was questionable at best.

Comment: Even without gunpowder, you could subject your enemy to a ***bombardment*** with rocks flung from catapults.

Comment: A *[shotgun approach](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/shotgun-approach)* is an indiscriminate, unfocused attack on something, and it's not clear from your example whether this is actually what you're looking for. If "They threw everything at him" in a coordinated fashion, they aren't taking a *shotgun approach*. Can you clarify?

Comment: A **Flail** is possibly a medieval equivalent to a shotgun: relatively indescriminate but effective over a wider area than a sword, say.

Comment: In a fantasy world you should feel free to make up your own word.

Comment: Please do not ask for help writing (or proofreading). They are out of scope and your question may be removed. [(more)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: What have you got against "threw everything at"?

Answer (score 2):

The term *[flight](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=flight)* as in *flight of arrows* can mean

> Sense of "a number of things passing through the air together" is from mid-13c.

*Etymonline.com*

Answer (score 0):

Scattershot might be an option. 
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scattershot

Comment: Without gunpowder what is doing the scattering and what is this stuff called *shot*?

Comment: @Jim A sinew-spring driven catapult was fully capable of hurling payloads of everything from loose gravel and stone to the more extreme and degrading batches of dead animals and septic waste.

Comment: @Stan - The link above says “First known use of scattershot 1951”

Comment: True. I saw the first-used thing too. But arrows too were shot, and so the word will pass muster in a period setting.